# Easy to Mine Cryptocurrency

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-profitability

I'm new to this field.It seems that mining Bitcoins using a normal computer has become tough.I have got a normal laptop with Intel i5 processor and GeForce 930MX graphics card.Which is the easiest coin to mine and get some real money(how less does not matter)

Just wanna try and see how it works.
Out of curiosity.

Thanks

Comment: I managed to get a couple of mBTC from mining on a GTX 745 using things like [NiceHash](https://www.nicehash.com/) and [ZPool](http://www.zpool.ca/), which can both pay you in BTC for mining altcoins. If you have Windows, the profit switcher on NiceHash works quite well. It's not like you're going to get rich from this though, but if you're just doing it to see how it works, try that.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Thanks for the reply.It seems I need to use cloud mining and purchase mining power... Right?

Comment: No... what I did was mined on my own PC. I probably lost more in electricity than I earned, but I did mine a few mBTC. See [this](https://www.nicehash.com/?p=nhmintro) for a profit-switching miner on Windows.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Thanks.. Will check it out.Did you get your BTC exchanged for currency ?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own coin, do a Ninja launch, know how to point appropriate pre-booked hash at low rates, do exceptional marketing, make lot's of false promises about a road map, ensure all the pools that mine altcoins pick up for the launch (pre-negotiated). Have a roadmap for development filled with false promises and tons of nonsense, a gimick can help.

Launch your nodes; launch, mine the majority stake of the supply, then manipulate the price using multiple accounts on the exchanges using automated trading software, creating tons of volume thus drawing attention.

Cycle this endlessly, up and down, and basically milk every newbie who enters the game on how it works... You only learn the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

> Which is the easiest coin to mine

Bitcoin testnet-in-a-box. Just connect two instances of client to each other.

> and get some real money(how less does not matter)

is "zero money" acceptable answer?